# Prove a limit using the formal definition of the limit

Tags: limits, definition, pi

So I have a sequence 
$\{a_n\} =  \frac{\pi}{2^n}$ where $n=1,2,3,4 \dots$ And I need to prove that its limit is $0$. Here is what  have done, can someone check and tell me if this is correct?

**Definition**: A sequence $\{a_n\}$ has a limit $L$ if and only if for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n>N,|a_n-L|<\epsilon$.

A sequence that has a limit $L$ is called a convergent sequence and we say that the sequence converges to $L$. If a sequence $\{a_n\}$  converges to a limit $L$, we write $\{a_n\} \to L$ as $n \to \infty$ or $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ of $\{a_n\}=L$. If a sequence does not have a limit, then we say that the sequence diverges.

So for our sequence given that $\epsilon>0$ we want $|\frac{\pi}{2^n} |<\epsilon~~ \forall n>N$.

So
$|\frac{\pi}{2^n} |<\epsilon =\frac{\pi}{2^n} <\epsilon$ Because $n$ is strictly positive making the whole left side of the inequality positive.

Solving for $n$:

$$\frac{\pi}{2^n} <\epsilon$$

$$2^n<\frac{\pi}{\epsilon}$$

$$n \log 2 < \log \frac{\pi}{\epsilon}$$

$$n < \log( \frac{\pi}{\epsilon}-2)$$

So if you take N to be any integer such that $N> \log(\frac{\pi}{\epsilon}-2)$, then for all  $\epsilon >0$ we have $|\frac{\pi}{2^n} |<\epsilon~~ \forall n>N$, and hence we have shown that $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ of $\{A_n\}=L$

Sorry that it looks like this but I don't know how to format text in here.

Comment: When you put dollar signs $\$ around equations they show up in "math mode", looking more appealing and allowing for the use of mathematical symbols. The language used is that of latex: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX

Comment: Disclaimer - I edited ONLY Latex formatting, all of the OP's mistakes stayed. The most obvious one: from $n \log 2 < \log \frac{\pi}{\epsilon}$ **doesn't follow**  $n < \log( \frac{\pi}{\epsilon}-2)$ Logarithms don't work like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea. Once you get to the point $\frac{\pi}{2^n} < \epsilon$, the algebra gives $n>\frac{\log\left(\pi/\epsilon\right)}{\log{2}}$. Your solution switched the order of the inequality, and brought the 2 into the log incorrectly.

Comment: Oh obviously you can bring the number into the log whilst subtracting not dividing. Im doing maths entire day sorry for that. so the N has to be chosen to be bigger than log(pi/e)/log(2) and we are sorted?

Comment: Correct. Choose some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ larger than $\log(\pi/e)/\log(2)$. This $N$ will be the smallest choice of $n$ allowable. Then for any $n\geq N$, you have $$ \left| \frac{\pi}{2^n}-0\right|\leq\left| \frac{\pi}{2^N}\right|<\epsilon .$$
Therefore, because $\epsilon$ is an arbitrary positive number, you have finally shown that you can make the 'tail' of the sequence as close to zero as you like.